# ERROR: subquery must return only one column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, select, aws-rds-data-service

I'm trying to write a select statement that requires the stored procedure in PostgreSQL. But, it fails by this error:
`ERROR:  subquery must return only one column.` 
The query is as follow:

```
select(
(select 
'q1_parasiticide_carton_rebate' as rewardName,
case when  q1_parasiticide_carton_rebate is null then CAST(0 as VARCHAR)
else cast(coalesce(q1_parasiticide_carton_rebate,0) as VARCHAR(10)) end as rewardAmount
from temptable 
),
(select 
'q2_parasiticide_carton_rebate' as rewardName,
case when  q2_parasiticide_carton_rebate is null then CAST(0 as VARCHAR)
else cast(coalesce(q2_parasiticide_carton_rebate,0) as VARCHAR(10)) end as rewardAmount
from temptable
))
from temptable;
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Your query have two syntax errors at line 7 and 13...

Comment: the error message is clear , what are you trying to do ? please provide sample data and desired output